# Deserialize JSON with repeating keys to a list inside Java Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, gson

If an "action" key-value pair is repeated, I want to append each associated "myObject" to a list as shown below. Is there a way to achieve this using GSON or JACKSON? Unfortunately, there is no option to edit the input JSON. If the ask is not clear, please let me know.

Input

```
[
  {
    myObject: {
      name: "foo",
      description: "bar"
    },
    action: "create",
  },
  {
    myObject: {
      name: "baz",
      description: "qux"
    },
    action: "create",
  },
];
```

Required Output

```
{
    "action": "create",
    "myObject": [
        {
          name: "foo",
          description: "bar"
        },
        {
          name: "baz",
          description: "qux"
        },
    ]
};
```

I am new to JSON parsing in Java and unfortunately haven't found a use case like mine on StackOverflow. I have tried configuring my ObjectMapper like so -

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

and using

```
@JsonAnySetter
```

annotation, but haven't gotten them to work yet.

Comment: The 2 jsons are different object structures. Id create a separate java class that represents the structure that i want my json to emulate, then transform that to json.

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up the required output. The entire "Required Output" should be inside square brackets as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with two separate model classes, one for the original structure and one for the transformed one. For simplicity I call them `OriginalModel` and `TransformedModel` below, you should probably pick more meaningful names. The following code uses Gson but you can probably achieve something similar with Jackson as well.

```java
class OriginalModel {
    String action;
    MyObjectData myObject;
}

class TransformedModel {
    String action;
    List<MyObjectData> myObject;

    public TransformedModel(String action, List<MyObjectData> myObject) {
        this.action = action;
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }
}

class MyObjectData {
    String name;
    String description;
}
```

If you declare these classes as nested classes you should make them `static`.

Then you can first parse the JSON data with the original model class, manually create the desired result structure using the transformed class and serialize that to JSON:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<OriginalModel> originalData = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<OriginalModel>>() {});

// Group MyObjectData objects by action name
// Uses LinkedHashMap to preserve order
Map<String, List<MyObjectData>> actionsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (OriginalModel model : originalData) {
    actionsMap.computeIfAbsent(model.action, k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(model.myObject);
}

List<TransformedModel> transformedData = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<MyObjectData>> entry : actionsMap.entrySet()) {
    transformedData.add(new TransformedModel(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}

String transformedJson = gson.toJson(transformedData);
```